# Exclude WooCommerce terminations from YOAST

Tags: hooks, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

Today i have a little issue with Yoast SEO, i would love to hide some pages from Sitemap.xml generated by Yoast.

The problem that when i exlude the ID in the Exlude panel in Backoffice it works perfectly for the ID.

Here is my issue : 
URL/mon-compte/edit-address/
URL/mon-compte/view-order/

I still have this link on my sitemap.xml

Any solution to exlude those page via a Hook or an other way from showing in Sitemap.XML ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are WooCommerce end-points. I don't see any filters for the yoast sitemap except for stuff like taxonomies. I think you could submit it as a feature requests trough their github page.

https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues

Comment: Huuuh i was thinking about the exclude options by page that i can use to make change about Slug to exclude some URL.

I will try to submit it as a feature requests thank you Niels.

Comment: Yeah, but the endpoint do not have a physical page ID... so that will not work :).

Comment: Totally, hope that we will get a feedback very soon from the Yoast Founder, because it's a large number of woocommerce that shouldn't be indexed!! or be in the sitemap.

Comment: if you are interested and can make a little push to the team https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/5915